# Show number of sold products but be first for less than 2

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

Looking for some help to show the total number of an item sold on the product page, but when it's less than 2 to have a prompt to be the first with a coupon code.

This is the code I have so far for theme functions

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_units_sold_counts', 19 );
function my_units_sold_counts($units_sold) {
    global $product;
    $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
    return $units_sold;
}
   function soldUnits ($units_sold) {
if ($units_sold <= 2 ) {

  echo '<p style="font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: 900; color: #908c8c;">No units sold yet. Be the first and use coupon code: xyz</p>';
} else {
 echo '<p style="font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: 900; color: #908c8c;">' . '<i style="margin-right: 10px;"class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>' . sprintf( __( 'Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
}
}
```

I can't seem to get my head around it and it's hurting.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if anyone else is looking for the answer for this I figured it out after a bit more sleep. I had to get rid of the return and the second function. 
So the code now looks like this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_units_sold_counts', 19 );
function my_units_sold_counts($units_sold) {
    global $product;
    $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );

if ($units_sold <= 2 ) {
  echo '<p style="font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: 900; color: #908c8c;">No units sold yet. Be the first and use coupon code: xyz</p>';
} else {
 echo '<p style="font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: 900; color: #908c8c;">' . '<i style="margin-right: 10px;"class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>' . sprintf( __( 'Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
}
}
```